# How to control UserID in pymqi?

Tags: python-3.x, authorization, ibm-mq, pymqi

Got a trouble:

- IBM MQ Server v9.1.0.0
- pymqi==1.11.1

When trying connect to server got an error:

```
pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2035: FAILED: MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
```

When I check traffic in Wireshark i got that:
[image: Actual result]

And in server log this:

```
07/31/2020 10:08:02 AM - Process(27333.5) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(host) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.1.0.0) QMgr(queue_manager)
                    Time(2020-07-31T07:08:02.253Z)
                    ArithInsert1(2) ArithInsert2(2035)
                    CommentInsert1(haha)
                   
AMQ9557E: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed for 'haha'.

EXPLANATION:
The call to initialize the User ID 'haha' failed with CompCode 2 and Reason
2035. If an MQCSP block was used, the User ID in the MQCSP block was ''.
ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
```

My code sample:

```py
import pymqi

host = "host"
port = 1416

conn_info = f"{host}({port})"
channel = "channel"

queue_manager = "queue_manager"


def main():
    manager = pymqi.connect(queue_manager=queue_manager, channel=channel, conn_info=conn_info)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried to execute the code from other devices and there, accordingly, the account under which I ran was taken as the UserID.

After that I asked our support to deal with the problem, after which I was able to connect with an account **haha**, but the solution with the creation of a list of allowed users does not suit me. Is there any way to control the UserID that is sent by `pymqi`?

---

### UPD 04.08.2020

The support team said that the user `phoenix` was created on the IBM MQ server with the password `123456789`, tried to send an MQSCP:

```py
manager = pymqi.connect(queue_manager=queue_manager, channel=channel,
            conn_info=conn_info, user="phoenix", password="123456789")
```

And got similar error `MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED` and server log contains error as above with username of machine where code launches (not `phoenix`).

Comment: Did you try passing a userid and password?   There are samples on the pymqi github repository that show this.   Your queue manage would need to have CONNAUTH enabled.  Short of that or creating/impersonating the user on your local system with pymqi there is no way for you to send an alternate userid.

Comment: @JoshMc Tried with user and password, UserID is sent before this data, response is the same. *>creating/impersonating the user on your local system with pymqi* - сreate user with pymqi? Did I understand correctly?

Comment: no at the system level.  If sending MQCSP  didn't help it is because the MQ Admin has disabled CONNAUTH.  They are trusting you to send a valid userid.  This leaves them open to spoofing.  Can you please add similar example to your post showing the MQCSP configuration you tried.   I assume most answers will simply point this out so best to point out you tried this.

Comment: @JoshMc Sorry, but i dont understand what is *MQCSP configuration*. Can you explain, please? And can I show my configuration?

Comment: Check out my comments on [pymqi issue 74](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/74#issuecomment-417842453) and [pymqi issue 140](https://github.com/dsuch/pymqi/issues/140).  Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: To clarify my 1st comment, adding a comma where needed: Short of that or creating/impersonating the user on your local system, with pymqi there is no way for you to send an alternate userid.

Comment: @JoshMc Ok. Understand. Is it because of the pymqi implementation? Or of the using IBM MQ client? And there is no way not to pass UserID (In other words: is this UserID necessary?)? Because there are suspicions that IBM MQ thinks this is an authorized connection due to UserID.

Comment: I went into great detail in comment linked on #74.  MQ client allways sends the user the process runs under in all APIs except Java and JMS.  I'll write an answer on this question later today.

Comment: @JoshMc Added info about MQCSP if I understand this entity correctly.

Comment: The queue manager CONNAUTH AUTHINFO needs to have `ADOPTCTX(YES)` to use the authenticated user for authorization.

Comment: @JoshMc Could you post an answer here so that I can create a translated association on ru SO?